# Android AsyncHttpClient insert data into database using Json

Tags: android, json

I'm using `AsyncHttpClient` library to insert textfield values to database.this is my code.but it's not insert data to data base.it return Log value `[0]` and Toast `fail`.

```
 AsyncHttpClient client=new AsyncHttpClient();
        RequestParams params=new RequestParams();
        params.put("loc_latitude", mLat.getText().toString());
        params.put("loc_longitude", mLon.getText().toString());
        params.put("loc_altitude", mAlt.getText().toString());

        client.post(SERVICE_URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject json) {

                try {
                    String value = json.getString("posts");
                    Log.e("val",value.toString());
                    if(value.equals("[0]"))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(SCS.this,"Fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(SCS.this,"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
```

And this is my  servere side PHP script.

```
include('connection.php');
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
$post = 0;
$posts = array();
$location_info_id                                   = null;
$loc_latitude                                       = isset($obj->{'loc_latitude'}) ? $obj->{'loc_latitude'} : null;
$loc_longitude                                      = isset($obj->{'loc_longitude'}) ? $obj->{'loc_longitude'} : null;
$loc_altitude                                       = isset($obj->{'loc_altitude'}) ? $obj->{'loc_altitude'} : null;
if (!empty($loc_latitude) && !empty($loc_longitude)) {



$sql = "INSERT INTO test_location (location_info_id, loc_latitude, loc_longitude, loc_altitude) VALUES ('". $location_info_id."','". $loc_latitude."','". $loc_longitude."','". $loc_altitude."')";

   if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE) {

       $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
       $post = $last_id;

    } else {
        $post = 0;
     }



}

$posts = array($post);

header('Content-type: application/json');
print json_encode(array('posts' => $posts));

$conn->close();
```

Comment: can you show server side code?

Comment: Which database? Please provide your database-insert code.

Comment: @MustanserIqbal I have add my serverside code .please check it

Comment: @JörnBuitink i have add database insert code.please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a MYSQL database you can do this using PHP.

Then this is the code you need to add to insert a new record in the database:

```
public class NewProductActivity extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputName;
EditText inputPrice;
EditText inputDesc;

// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://api.androidhive.info/android_connect/create_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

    // Edit Text
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
    inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

    // Create button
    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

    // button click event
    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Don't forget you also need to add the JSON Parser Class:

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

Finally you need to add the PHP script to insert the row into the table.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you.but i want to go with AsyncHttpClient library

Comment: Isn't the above AsyncHttp client?